# Scan a list/range of IP addresses to find out which SSL Certificates each one is using

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, nmap

I have a list of internal IP addresses 1000+ strong, most of which I suspect are running services on port 443 and therefore will have a certificate installed on the server. These ips all exist on three seperate /24 subnets. My goal is to find out which are using a specific wildcard cert so I know to include that server on our list of devices that we'll need to renew the certificate on when it expires.

I don't have hostnames for these ips as most are devices that won't resolve like firewalls/switches but will still have a certificate installed somewhere (I think)

So far I've tried a few variations of the below, but openssl can't seem to accept cidr format or IP ranges.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 10.x.x.x/24:443 </dev/null
```

Our wildcard certificate that's used widely across our internal server estate is due to expire soon and we need to ascertain on which servers it is being used.

Comment: Consider the possibility of SNI, which will make going just by IP address useless.

Answer (score 3):

`nmap` has an  script named [ssl-cert](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-cert.html) that is built just for this.

```
nmap -p 443 --script ssl-cert 10.0.0.0/24
```